# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a Yoga-Node to a parent without a measure function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, native-base

I'm trying to make a simple login page with React Native, React Navigation Native Base and Expo on Android/Windows, but when I preview the application, I get this error :
[image]

How can this error be remedied? 
My application includes, in App.js, React Navigation which redirects to the AuthScreen page if the user is not authenticate. When I click Dismiss, I can see my login page, without the text on the buttons, like this :

[image]

Here is the AuthScreen code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Form, Item, Label, Input, Text, Button } from 'native-base';

import * as auth from '../engine/AuthScreenModel';

export default class AuthScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Form>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', padding: 20 }}>
            Welcome! Create an account or login to continue.
          </Text>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Username</Label>
            <Input
              onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
              returnKeyType="next"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input
              onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
              returnKeyType="go"
              secureTextEntry
            />
          </Item>
          <Button
            full
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            onPress={() => auth.login(this.state.email, this.state.password, navigate)}>
            >
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button
            full
            success
            style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
            onPress={() => auth.register(this.state.email, this.state.password, navigate)}>
            >
            <Text>Create an account</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
});
```

Comment: As suggested here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243 You might require at least one View component to wrap the rest, at least on Android.

Comment: @Striped Adding the View component to include all components does not work...

Comment: I read `I just updated to the newest release of react native and it seems to have resolved this issue;`. Try to update to the react-native latest version.

Comment: @Striped Do I need to upgrade to version 54.2? Expo only supports up to version 52, right?

Comment: It looks like you're doubling up your Buttons' end tags after your onPress props. `>>` instead of just `>`